# Not able to return simple function in c++ - syntax problem

Tags: c++, function

Why do i get the error code **id return 1 exit status**
I need to practice function calling but im struggling calling the 3 functions.
I need to understand how to correctly call function in this exemple really.
Do i need to declare a main function? According to the exercice, i dont think i do.

```
 #include <iostream>



 using namespace std;

/**
 * Following function prints a message into the console
 */ 
void say_hello(){

    cout << "Hello, World!" << endl;
}

/**
 *  The following function prints the sum of 2 integer numbers into the console, the numbers are 
 *  passed as parameter
 */ 
void print_sum(int a, int b){
    cout << "Sum is: " << a+b << endl;
}


/**
 * The following function calculates the product of 2 integer parameter passed and returs the product to the caller.
 */ 
int getProduct(int a, int b){
    int p = a * b;
    return p;
}



   void writeYourCode(int first, int second){

 // Instruction 1: Please write a statement to call the function say_hello just after this line
        say_hello();


 // Instruction 2: Please write a statement to call the function print_sum and pass first and second as parameter

        print_sum(first, second);



// Instruction 3: Please write a statement to call the function getProduct and pass first and second as parameter, 
 //                catch the return value in an integer variable declared by you. 
 //                Print that integer containing the result into console using cout, there  must be a newline at the end.
 //                You need to print only the result and a new line    

        int total = getProduct(first,second);
        cout << total << endl;



    }
```

Comment: Where is your `main` function?

Comment: This is not a site to learn the basics of C++ from - for that you will need a good C++ textbook.

Comment: @NathanOliver i was wondering if i need one for this exercice

Comment: You always need a `main` function if you want the code to run

Comment: How is your code being run? Is this file `#include`d in another source file that has a `main` which calls your code?

Comment: *"id return 1 exit status"* It's not `Id`, it's `ld` - the linker.

Answer (score 0):

As previously noted in your question comments, you need to implement a `main()` function. In simple words, your main is the *entrance point* for your program.

Therefore, you have correctly implemented some functions, but need a `main()` to use it. It has a structure like the following:

```cpp
int main() {
    // you can call your functions from here!
}
```

There are many things to know about the `main()` function. You can find all the details [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/main_function).

Answer (score -1):

You need to write a main() function after all of your function definitions. You can either use int main or void main. If you used void main, you don't need to **return 0**

```
    int main(){
      int first = 10;
      int second = 3;
      say_hello();
      getProduct(5, 3);
      print_sum(first, second);
      return 0;
}
```

Comment: `void main()` is wrong. The standard states that `main()` must return an int. Reaching the end of `main()` without reaching a return statement implicitly returns 0 (unlike other non-void functions where this would be undefined behavior).